# How to fix problem with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?

Tags: python, django

I am pretty beginner in django and in coding too. Stuck for a while with an error. Will really appreciate if someone's help me!I tried to google it and it gave me a lot of solutions, I tried them but it gave errors too. What should I write to make things done? I took this code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a48xeeo5Vnk&list=PL-osiE80TeTtoQCKZ03TU5fNfx2UY6U4p&index=2

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

And it gave me this error:

````
  File "urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 153, in get_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.```
````

Comment: What is the file called where you included the url_patterns? And where is it located?

Comment: Exactly how are you running this code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added your app to INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py and that you imported the model correctly in the admin.py file.

If that doesn't work, you probably need to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE -

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
```

You can see it in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings).